# Possible to set HTML table to be max of percentage or a specific number of pixels?

Tags: html

I want the columns of my HTML table to be the max of a certain percentage of the screen or a minimum number of pixels, so if the user has a 1024x768 display the table columns won't be all scrunched up ( and may require some scrolling ) and if a user has a 1920x1600 screen they can get more information.  Is this possible using the html table construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at using min-width, max-width etc.  something [like this](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/width.html) would be great.

NOTE: as mentioned in the comments IE6 does not work with these options.

Comment: Just a warning, min-width and max-width do not work on IE6.  If you need to support that browser, you'll have to find one of the many workarounds.  (A Google search should suffice for finding them.)